# Is this Lemma true in first-order intuitionistic logic?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have the following first-order lemma:

```
Lemma nop_firstorder :
     forall (n n1 n2:nat) (input: list nat),
          ( (exists p : prog, isValidProg p input -> execProg p [] input = Some [n;n1;n2]) ->
              (exists p : prog, isValidProg p input -> execProg p [] input = Some [n]) ) ->
          ( (forall p : prog, isValidProg p input -> execProg p [] input <> Some [n]) ->
              (forall p : prog, isValidProg p input -> execProg p [] input <> Some [n;n1;n2]) ).
```

It seems true in first-order classical logic, but I can't prove it with the first-order tactic firstorder, even with a search depth of 500.

Is this (form of) lemma false in first-order intuitionist logic ?

Comment: What makes you think this is classically true? It does not seem to me that this is the case.

Comment: Well, to be honest, just a 'natural language' intuition like : if everytime I have a valid program that produces Some [n;n1;n2] as a result, there is also a valid program that produces Some [n], than if no valid program produces Some [n], than the fact that a valid program can produce [n;n1;n2] would violate the first assumption. This intuition is probably not enough : I'l try to use a first-order solver to validate/invalidate this 'natural language' intuition.

Answer (score 2):

You mistranslated your natural language intuition into Coq: your first clause says that every time you have a valid program producing `Some [n;n1;n2]`, there is a program that, *if it is valid*, produces `Some [n]`. To fit your intuition, you would have to transform that clause into

```
(exists p : prog, isValidProg p input -> execProg p [] input = Some [n;n1;n2]) ->
(exists p : prog, isValidProg p input /\ execProg p [] input = Some [n])
```

In which case `firstorder` happily solves your goal, without any classical assumptions needed.

Comment: Oups... thank you fixing the translation. It seems I need something like this for Coq https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.12615.pdf